# JavaFX ScrollPane: The scrollbars partially hidden

Tags: java, javafx

I have discovered an anomaly I wonder may be a JavaFX bug with ScrollPane or perhaps just a problem with my composition.

The root node is a BorderPane. The left content is a sidebar using a VBox. This sidebar does not have a scrollpane. The center content is a ScrollPane.

```
BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
MenuBar top = new MenuBar();
root.setTop(top);

VBox left = new VBox();
root.setLeft(left);

ScrollPane center = new ScrollPane();
root.setCenter(center);
```

When the window is resized in height smaller than the left content, the scrollbars lower bounds are not visible.

These screenshots illustrate the "bug":
[image]
[image]

Here is a small test application I have to reproduce this with:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.Menu;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.control.TitledPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ScrollPaneApplication extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ScrollPaneApplication.launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        root.setPadding(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));

        final Menu menu1 = new Menu("File");
        final Menu menu2 = new Menu("Options");
        final Menu menu3 = new Menu("Help");

        final MenuBar menuBar = new MenuBar();
        menuBar.getMenus().addAll(menu1, menu2, menu3);
        root.setTop(menuBar);

        VBox leftBox = new VBox();
        addLabel(leftBox);
        leftBox.setSpacing(10);
        root.setLeft(leftBox);

        VBox box1 = new VBox();
        box1.setSpacing(10);
        addLabel(box1);

        VBox box2 = new VBox();
        box2.setSpacing(10);
        addLabel(box2);
        VBox box3 = new VBox();
        box3.setSpacing(10);
        addLabel(box3);
        VBox box4 = new VBox();
        box4.setSpacing(10);
        addLabel(box4);
        VBox box5 = new VBox();
        box5.setSpacing(10);
        addLabel(box5);

        HBox box = new HBox();
        box.setSpacing(10);
        box.getChildren().addAll(box1, box2, box3, box4, box5);

        ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane();
        scrollPane.setContent(box);
        root.setCenter(scrollPane);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 1024, 1024);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private void addLabel(VBox parentBox) {
        TitledPane pane1 = new TitledPane();
        pane1.setPadding(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));
        pane1.setText("Loop 1");
        VBox box1 = new VBox();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            box1.getChildren().add(new Label("Label " + i));
        }
        pane1.setContent(box1);

        TitledPane pane2 = new TitledPane();
        pane2.setPadding(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));
        pane2.setText("Loop 2");
        VBox box2 = new VBox();
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            box2.getChildren().add(new Label("Label " + j));
        }
        pane2.setContent(box2);

        TitledPane pane3 = new TitledPane();
        pane3.setPadding(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));
        pane3.setText("Loop 3");
        VBox box3 = new VBox();
        for (int k = 0; k < 10; k++) {
            box3.getChildren().add(new Label("Label " + k));
        }
        pane3.setContent(box3);
        parentBox.getChildren().addAll(pane1, pane2, pane3);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TLDR: you just need to tell javafx that it can resize leftbox, simpy add

```
leftBox.setMinHeight(0);
```

to your sources;

The point there is that you have this left VBox, and it`s height  fixed right now, cause you have not specified min, max and preferred height. When you try to resize windows left VBox height stay fixed. And if you look on BorderPane layout

[image]

you will see, that center region(where you have scroll pane) on the same row with left(where you have left VBox), so center min height limited by left height.
And when you resizing windows center height does not change, so your scrollpane height does not change, and it thinks, that there still nothing to scroll. while it falls out from your viewport

To change this you need to tell javaFX that it can resize left VBox height down to needed values. And it will happen by default on windows resize.

```
 leftBox.setMinHeight(0);
```

says, that it can resize leftBox size even to zero if needed.

Comment: How simple. It did not occur to me. You write GridPane, but I guess you mean BorderPane.